# Magento :: Arabic words in invoice pdf print

Tags: magento-1.7

When I tried to print invoice pdf with Arabic words its giving like separate characters instead of complete meaningful Arabic word.

Its sort of alphabetic listing with these Arabic words.

Anybody please advise, its an important project for me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

//Add the font file(.ttf) like below in php code.

```
$font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath(Mage::getBaseDir() . '/lib/LinLibertineFont/your-lang-custom-font.ttf');
```

//set header as UTF-8.

```
ini_set('default_charset', 'utf-8');
```